# Check if value in list

Tags: python

I'm attempting to check if a string element(s) are contained in a list.

Code :

```
if('a' in ['notin']):
    print('test')
```

Does not print a value, which makes sense.

Code :

```
if('a' or 'b' or 'c' in ['notin']):
    print('test')
```

prints `test` . Why is 'test' printed as `a` , `b` or `c` is not in `notin` ?

I'm not implementing this conditional correctly ?

This is not a duplicate question as solution based on reading comments I've written is unique :

```
if any (t in ['a' , 'b' , 'c'] for t in ['a' , 'b']) :
    print('in list')

if not any (t in ['a' , 'b' , 'c'] for t in ['d' , 'e']) :
    print('not in list')
```

Comment: In short: `'a' or 'b' or 'c' in ['notin']` is evaluated as `bool('a') or bool('b') or ('c' in ['notin'])` and `bool('a')` is `True`. Use `any` instead.

Comment: I would put a,b,c in one list and than loop to check if that is available in another list.

Comment: Also, note that even `'n' in ['notin']` would yield `False`, as it tests membership in the _list_, not in the string _within_ the list. Try `any(c in "notin" for c in ('a', 'b', 'c'))`, i.e. without the `[...]` around the string.

Comment: @blue-sky Still quite complicated, `any((x in "notin" for x in ("a", "b", "c")))` would do.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you get `test` showing is that the evaluation is seen as

```
((('c' in 'notin') or 'b') or 'a')
((( FALSE ) or TRUE ) or TRUE )
```

since

```
if ('b'):
    print ('test')
```

evaluates to 'TRUE' and prints 'test' so does your sample.  The short answer is yes you implemented your conditional incorrectly.

Comment: This does not work (testing if 'o' is in 'notin' yields false). Please don't post answers with untested suggestions ...

Comment: Correction, actually it just tests `if ('a' in ['notin'])`, as `('a' or 'b' or 'c')` evaluated to just `'a'`. Still wrong.